# Normalizing specific cloumn of specific multiple row in panda

Tags: pandas, normalize

The data frame have several same ID in first Column, I want to normalize each column based on the same ID

I made a random df below for simplicity.
df:

| ID | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 1 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| 12000 | 20 | 12 | 19 |
| 12000 | 30 | 13 | 54 |
| 12000 | 55 | 14 | 78 |
| 12000 | 60 | 18 | 90 |
| 12000 | 79 | 15 | 78 |

the hard part is ID are not in sequence and I can not use "for i: i+1" cycle.
so here is my question, for example for the each same ID rows I want to normalize each columns of B,C,D separately, the point is I dont have any clue how to do it

I will normalize the column B and C based on the min and Max value

```
    cols_to_norm = ['B','C']
    df[cols_to_norm] = df[cols_to_norm].apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
```

and for the Column D, I use a specific formula

```
    df['D'] = df['D'].sub(df['D'].iat[0])/df['D'].std()
```

I expect to normalize each columns like above only for their specific ID, for instance for ID=1 only 3 rows per column will be normalized, and for ID=12000 the 5 rows will be normalize.

Comment: Normalize how? Can you provide the expected output (maybe using a more minimal example, 2/3 IDs, 2/3 rows each)

Comment: then just do the same with a `groupby('ID')`

Comment: @mozway the point is, I have 10K 'ID' and it is not possible to do normalization one by one,

Comment: df_out = df.set_index(['Id',df.groupby (['Id']).cumcount()+1]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}' .format)